# Mikro EntityManager in NestJS bull processor not working

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm, nestjsbull

I want to make some queries in the task processor:

```
@Processor('audio')
export class AudioProcessor {

  constructor(private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {

  }

  @Process()
  public async process(job: Job<any>) {
    // ! this promise never resolve
    const user = await this.entityManager.findOne(User, { id: 1 });
  }
}
```

The promise will never be resolved in the `@Process()` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there is an error thrown here

```js
@Process()
public async process(job: Job<any>) {
  // error thrown below
  const user = await this.entityManager.findOne(User, { id: 1 });
}
```

The correct solution is use the `@UseRequestContext()` decorator and `orm` property in constructor.

```js
constructor(
    private readonly orm: MikroORM) {

}

@Process()
@UseRequestContext()
public async process(job: Job<any>) {
  // error thrown below
  const user = await this.entityManager.findOne(User, { id: 1 });
}
```

- https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/pull/3475